# What is managed dns?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I would like to know about managed DNS?
And also what is different be nameserver and DNS server?

Please provide me suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed DNS is much like a managed server, a provider of the service does the full management for you. The services will provide different levels of service but typically they'll give you a control panel to manage your DNS records. One primary benefit of such a service is the ability to distribute the name servers geographically to protect against outages.

Nameserver and DNS server are generally the same thing. Nameserver is just anything that translates names to some other identifier, like an IP. The majority of nameservers use the DNS protocol so that's why I say generally the same thing.

One suggestion off the top of my head would be http://www.dyndns.com

Comment: Some providers in this space will walk you through setting up certain record types.